# IF statement in Excel that looks at the value of a cell being a date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

How would I create an `if` statement within a cell that looks at another cell's value and copies the value to it if it is a date. If it's not a date it leaves the cell blank.

So far I have come up with something like this but it is obviously not working:

```
=if('TRACKING FILE'!I10=DATE,'TRACKING FILE'!I10, "")
```

Comment: If you are positive it will be formatted as a date, you can use `If(Left(Cell("format",myCell),1) = "D", myCell, "")`

Comment: Are you referring to dates as considered by "Excel" or even actual dates like 1/1/1800

Comment: Well they are actual dates, but they are also formatted as dates within excel. I'm not too sure of what you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy")))),TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"),"")
```

This copies numeric representation of dates or typical dates. Change the "true" according to your needs, depending on what you are going to do with it.

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(F9,"mm/dd/yyyy")))),F9,"")

=IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(F9,"mm/dd/yyyy")))),DATEVALUE(TEXT(F9,"mm/dd/yyyy")),"")
```

Comment: Actually, this would work for that, but it would format it to display as a date in the new field.

Comment: Correct, @Mathieu J, it works for that, as well as numeric dates.

Comment: It works for me too.  I don't think the conversion should be to text, though.  The OP asked for it to return either the date or a blank.

Comment: That is true @dDoug, but if you don't put that (or something, format was not specified) it will display as a number.  I am assuming he wants a visibly recognizable date.

Comment: I stand corrected, bad testing by me! Deleting my comment. And +1 for good stuff!

Comment: I'm basically using this to check data between two tabs on a spreadsheet. One tab has a column with dates and blanks and I just want to be able to copy the column exactly as is on my other tab.

Comment: @MathieuJ -> If you are just checking against blanks, there's a much simpler formula `=If(isblank(myCell),"",myCell) where myCell is your Cell Reference` However, if your data is mixed content, go with the answer(s) above.

Comment: Does it continue to work when people with different regional settings use this? I'm not sure if it's stable but I'd like to know.

Comment: @user1166147, I assumed that the OP would format the column the formula is in for a date.  I think that's preferable to "texting" it :).  I upvoted your answer right away though.

Comment: Lol, thanks! I wondered because the datevalue function requires explicitly a format.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate all the help guys. This place is great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct isdate function in Excel, but you can create your own function in VBA and apply it in your worksheet.

```
Function checkDate(oRange As Range) as boolean
    checkDate = isdate(oRange)
End Function
```

In your worksheet:

```
=IF(checkDate(C8) = TRUE;C8;"")
```

You need to set the format yourself, as Excel displays it standard as a number.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to stick to formulas within cells and can't use any macros on these worksheets. However, I appreciate the help and will keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @MathieuJ: then why did you tag your question as VBA?... (And to be clear, this *isn't* a macro but a user-defined function, usable as a formula within a cell.)

Comment: The contents of your function could simply be `checkDate = IsDate(oRange)`. Right now you're saying `If True Then True Else False` which is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, I tagged it as VBA because even though I am unable to use vba for this exact issue, I am not opposed to learning how VBA can help me with the same issue in the future.